# What do the percentages in Battery Saver mean?

Tags: 8.1, battery-saver

When I open the Battery Saver app, it shows me some percentage (e.g. **7.1%**, or **1.1%**, or **<1%**) after many apps.

What exactly do those percentages mean? Do they show battery usage? If so, what corresponds to 100%? The battery's total capacity? Or total usage by all apps?

How is it even possible to determine battery usage on a per-app basis? Does it simply measure total power consumption while the app is active? If so, wouldn't that also include activity by background processes? Or does it perhaps mean something else, like CPU usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage shows the battery power a specific app is consuming. In the latest update, the usage in the background is shown seperately.
The usage data scales to actual device battery capacity, so full width means 100% capacity.

More background information on is available here:

- [Battery saver help page](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/battery-making-it-last)
- [Latest battery saver release notes](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/battery-saver/c551f76f-3368-42bb-92df-7bfbb9265636)

Comment: Ah, the second link answers quite a few questions, thanks! But I'd still like to know how it's possible to measure battery usage for individual apps.

Comment: I guess they use something like windows performance counters for that. They also have extensive tools available for developers to measure battery consumption: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215907(v=vs.105).aspx